# R data.table convert date column to month

Tags: r, data.table, posixct, posixlt

I have the following toy `data.table`

```
 x = data.table(dt = c('2015-01-01','2015-02-01','2016-04-01'))
```

I'm trying to add an extra column to the table which has the three letter abbreviation of the date. I tried

```
 x$dt = strptime(x$dt,'%b')
```

but it gave back the following, a warning and an empty field.

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
  Supplied 9 items to be assigned to 3 items of column 'dt' (6 unused)
2: In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
  Coerced 'list' RHS to 'character' to match the column's type. Either    change the target column to 'list' first (by creating a new 'list' vector length 3 (nrows of entire table) and assign that; i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'character' (e.g. 1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the table and stick to it, please.

> x
          dt mnth
1: c(NA, NA, NA)     
2: c(NA, NA, NA)     
3: c(NA, NA, NA)
```

I found prior Q&A on SO that said that `strptime` returned a list but haven't been able to accomplish this relatively simple task. Could someone provide some pointers?

Comment: There is no 'mnth' in the example.  If `dt` is the column, `format(strptime(x$dt, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%b')`

Comment: Corrected/edited the question. Your solution works @akrun. Thanks.

Comment: or: `x[, mnth := months(strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d'))]`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `format`

```
format(strptime(x$dt, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%b')
```

Or as @Frank mentioned, the `format.Date` can be applied to `Date` class

```
format(as.Date(x$dt), "%b")
```

Comment: There's a `format.Date` method, and `as.Date` correctly parses the string, so `format(as.Date(x$dt), "%b")` is another option. Or, as Jaap mentioned, `months(as.Date(x$dt), abbr = TRUE)`